# exec() not working when trying to execute a string containing the command "abs.__doc__"

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to execute the command `abs.__ doc__` inside the `exec()` function but for some reason it does not work.

```
function = input("Please enter the name of a function: ")
proper_string = str(function) + "." + "__doc__"
exec(proper_string)
```

Essentially, I am going through a series of exercises and one of them asks to provide a short description of the entered function using the `__ doc__` attribute. I am trying with `abs.__ doc__` but my command line comes empty. When I run python in the command line and type in `abs.__ doc__` without anything else it works, but for some reason when I try to input it as a string into the `exec()` command I can't get any output. Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I have deliberately added spaces in this description concerning the attribute I am trying to use because I get bold type without any of the underscores showing.)

As a note, I do not think I have imported any libraries that could interfere, but these are the libraries that I have imported so far:

```
import sys
import datetime
from math import pi
```

My Python version is Python 3.10.4. My operating system is Windows 10.

Comment: Note `function` is _already_ a string, `input` always returns one, and concatenating multiple string literals together is baffling. `exec("abs.__doc__")` indeed doesn't output anything, there's no `print` or similar to provide any output.

Comment: Yes, function is already a string but I thought there was something wrong with the data type which is why I thought forcing a string would solve the problem. But I do not quite understand what is baffling about concatenating multiple string literals? Could you explain? Also, I tried enclosing exec() in such a way as to get print(exec()) but this didn't output anything as well.

Comment: What I meant is: why would you write `"." + "__doc__"` when you already have both values, rather than `".__doc__"`? For that matter Python has several options for string formatting you should use instead.

Comment: Alright, that is a fair argument. In this case, it is actually baffling that I concatenated my string in such a way. I should simplify my string concatenations indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abs.__doc__` is a string. You should use `eval` instead of `exec` to get the string.

Example:

```py
function = input("Please enter the name of a function: ")
proper_string = str(function) + "." + "__doc__"
doc = eval(proper_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using `globals()`:

```
def func():
  """Func"""
  pass

mine = input("Please enter the name of a function: ")
print(globals()[mine].__doc__)
```

`globals()` return a dictionary that keeps track of all the module-level definitions. `globals()[mine]` is just trying to lookup for the name stored in `mine`; which is a function object if you assign `mine` to `"func"`.

As for `abs` and `int` -- since these are builtins -- you can look it up directly using `getattr(abs, "__doc__")` or a more explicit: `getattr(__builtins__, "abs").__doc__`.

There are different ways to lookup for a python object corresponding to a given string; it's better not to use `exec` and `eval` unless  **really** needed.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your given code? I have copied it to my Python interpreter but when I try it with examples "abs" and "int" I get the following error message: Please enter the name of a function: abs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\sebas\Documents\PYTHON\BEGINNER\practice_01.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(globals()[function].__doc__)
KeyError: 'abs'

Comment: I have added that @SebastianSzymczyk. You can remove the above comment if you wish.